# passing a callback as upload_to to FileField

Tags: django, directory, filefield

I have an abstract model class UploadItem for handling uploaded files. I want each subclass to be able to define the upload_to path. For this, i  pass a callback to the constructor of FileField.

This is an example:

```
class UploadItem(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=UploadItem.get_directory) 


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
# I want videos to be storred in 'videos/' directory
class Video(UploadItem):
    def get_directory(self, instance, filename):
        return 'videos/'
```

But this doesn't work, i am getting this error:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=UploadItem.get_directory) 
NameError: name 'UploadItem' is not defined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is natural given that at the time of evaluating

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=UploadItem.get_directory)
```

the `UploadItem` class is not yet defined. You can do the following to make it work:

```
def get_directory():
    pass

class UploadItem(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_directory)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This won't solve all your problems though. Adding (or overriding) a method `get_directory` in the `Video` class will not change the `upload_to` property of the `file` attribute of the model.

**Update**

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) says that the `upload_to` can be a callable.

> This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system.

Given this we can write a custom call back function like this:

```
categories_and_paths = { 'video': 'videos/', 'photo': 'photos/' } # etc.
def get_directory(instance, filename):
    category = instance.category
    return categories_and_paths.get(category, '')
```

`Instance` here will be the instance of the respective model. For this to work each model instance should have a category field. We can add one in the body of the model.

```
class Video(UploadItem):
    category = 'video'
```

Comment: so what do you suggest to achieve whati i want to do? I want each subclass to redefine where to upload files. thanks

Comment: I see, i wanted the callback to be part of the class. But this is not possible. I will do it this way.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in a similar fashion with some tweaks if you need to use base class properties as part of a subclass:

```
import os

# ...

def get_directory(instance, filename):
    return instance.get_file_directory(filename)


class UploadItem(models.Model):
    FILE_DIRECTORY = 'files/'

    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_directory) 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @staticmethod
    def get_file_directory(filename):
        return os.path.join(UploadItem.FILE_DIRECTORY, filename)
```

And then in subclass:

```
class Video(UploadItem):
    FILE_DIRECTORY = 'videos/'

    def get_file_directory(self, filename):
        filename = os.path.join(self.FILE_DIRECTORY, filename)
        return super().get_document_path(filename)
```

This way you will have `upload_to` that equals:

- `files` for `UploadItem`
- `files/videos` for `Video`

Might be useful for more complex objects that require to share some common base property.