# Class attribute inheritance in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

There are two models:

```
class BaseImage(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PostImage(BaseImage):
    in_text = models.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseImage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image.upload_to = 'images/news/%Y/%m/%d'
```

How can I set **upload_to** property in the base model? This my attempt doesn't work:

```
        self.image.upload_to = 'images/news/%Y/%m/%d'
```

Comment: Here is a useful variation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669830/passing-a-callback-as-upload-to-to-filefield/41332610#41332610

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I can suggest is to write function to get upload to method from instance e.g.

in models.py

```
#default method to get file upload path
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return instance.get_upload_to_path(filename)

class BaseImage(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_to)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    #method on the class to provide upload path for files specific to these objects
    def get_upload_to_path(instance, filename):
         return 'images/'+filename

class PostImage(BaseImage):
    in_text = models.BooleanField()

    #method to provide upload path for PostImage objects
    def get_upload_to_path(instance, filename):
    #change date.year etc to appropriate variables
         return 'images/news/%Y/%m/%d' % (date.year, date.month, date.day)
```

Comment: I understand the idea, but your code is not clear enough. Please, make corrections for other people.

Comment: @art.zhitnik Added some comments, do they help?

Comment: If I understood right, instead of upload_to='images' must be upload_to=get_upload_to, and class methods must be named as get_upload_to_path, not get_upload_to.